# odbc connection sql server native client 10.0 failed evenly

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, odbc, ironspeed

```
     Dim cnnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filepath + filename
               Dim cnn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cnnStr)
                    Try
                        cnn.Open()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        cnnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filepath + filename
                        cnn = New OleDbConnection(cnnStr)
                        cnn.Open()
                    End Try
Dim ConnectionString As String = "Trusted_Connection=no;Server=AMAZONA-RPKEMQI;Database=ContactManager;Uid=sa;Pwd=Sql12345;"

                    Dim Accesscmd As New OleDbCommand
                    Accesscmd.Connection = cnn
                    'Accesscmd.CommandText = "SELECT * INTO [Email] FROM [Email] IN '' [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=servername;Database=ContactSync;Trusted_Connection=no;Uid=sa;Pwd=sa123;];"
                    ''Data Source=ADDIS16\SA;Database=ContactSync;Trusted_Connection=no;User Id=sa;Password=88888" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
                    'Accesscmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Try
                        Accesscmd.Connection.Open()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Accesscmd.Connection = cnn
                    End Try

                    Accesscmd.CommandText = " SELECT * INTO [tbl Industry] FROM [Industries] IN '' [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};" & ConnectionString & "];"
                    Accesscmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Hello i am trying to connect oledb mdf datasource to export through ironspeed but some how its doing weired behaviour like
first time its working well
and second time its throwing error

> odbc connection sql server native client 10.0 failed

I don't know what is happening its working vice versa i have spend whole day in this one

Comment: What is the full exception?

Comment: Its a full exception its can not connect once and can connect one i don't know what is the problem but seems very weired

Comment: Can you switch to an ADO provider?

Comment: Ya i can i have swap ado provider based on system 32-bit 12.0 and for 64 4.0 @AdamZuckerman